# aws cloudwatch empty data from get-metric-statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a couple of S3 buckets and Lambda functions.
There's a lot of data in the S3 bucket and the Lambda function has been used heavily. In fact, I managed to get a Grafana dashboard that is currently getting the Lambda Invocations apparently right (but no S3 bucket size). But when I request this data via CLI I'm getting empty results. I'm pretty sure the names are correct and there should be data in there. What am I missing? The user is attached to a CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess permission.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
   --namespace AWS/Lambda \
   --metric-name Invocations \
   --dimensions Name=FunctionName,Value=function_name1 \
   --statistics Maximum \
   --period 60 --start-time 2023-05-01T00:00:00 --end-time 2023-05-02T23:59:00
```

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
   --namespace AWS/S3 \
   --metric-name BucketSizeBytes \
   --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=bucket_name1\
   --statistics Maximum \
   --period 60 --start-time 2023-05-01T00:00:00 --end-time 2023-05-02T23:59:00
```

EDIT: as requested, here's the CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess policy used:

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : [
        "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Get*",
        "cloudwatch:List*",
        "logs:Get*",
        "logs:List*",
        "logs:StartQuery",
        "logs:StopQuery",
        "logs:Describe*",
        "logs:TestMetricFilter",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents",
        "logs:StartLiveTail",
        "logs:StopLiveTail",
        "oam:ListSinks",
        "sns:Get*",
        "sns:List*"
      ],
      "Resource" : "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : [
        "oam:ListAttachedLinks"
      ],
      "Resource" : "arn:aws:oam:*:*:sink/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks more like an IAM role issue. The permission `CloudWatchReadyOnly` might not be sufficient to fetch all the data for S3 and Lambda. Can you try granting the following permissions `cloudwatch:GetMetricData` and `cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics`. Please refer to list of permissions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/permissions-reference-cw.html